# Unable to include functions in history.js data

Tags: javascript, history.js

I have a single-page webapp that I'm trying to add history.js support to. Right now, the URL remains unchanged no matter what screen the user is on. My plan is to use `History.pushState()` to change the URL and include a function that, when executed, navigates the app from anywhere to the new screen. Here's what I have:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function() {
  var State = History.getState();
  console.log(State);
  State.data.navigate();
  History.log('statechange:', State.data, State.title, State.url);
});

// later

History.pushState({page: 'page1', navigate: function() {
  navigateToPage1();
}}, 'Page 1', '?page1');
```

The problem is, any function I add to the `data` object disappears when I go to retrieve it in the `statechange` event handler. Is there a workaround I can use, or do I have to have a massive `switch(State.data.page)` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rearchitecting the app to support history.js. In the long run it would be the more maintainable option anyway.